# How to pass value for @Query annotation from application.yml file on Repository Interface method?

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, mongorepository

I want to pass dynamic native queries based on my database specific profile. So how to read value from application.yml file for the @Query annotation?

```
public EmployeeRepo extends CRUDRepository<Employee, Integer>{

@Query("${my-query}")
List<Employee> findBy();

}


application.yml:
my-query: Some-query
```

.

Comment: I don't think you can do that since `@Query` expects a `String`, and it must be constant

Comment: Yes. But is it possible to fetch value from application.yml into @Query annotation on the interface methods?

Comment: That's precisely the thing you can't do. The parameters in annotations must be known at compile time, and the injection is produced at runtime, so there is no way you can dynamically inject values into annotations

Comment: I tried with AOP and reflection and able to change change/pass/modify the query value, but query is not firing with modified query.